# Blue screen appeared after Build & Run project in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So i made my first unity game. I run (play) the scene on unity every thing works fine. (no exceptions or error what so ever). Then i tried to Build & Run the project, but after launching the game, Unity splash screen appeared and than my screen was covered with complete blue screen. And nothing happens from there. Am i missing something?

**Important points to know**

1. My 2D game has no main menu options (start,restart,quit)
2. This is just a simple platformer game, i.e player run,jump on tiles,
       collect coins e.t.c
3. I have not created any of splash screen in start of game

Do i need to write some code to make it build and run from exe? please help

Comment: Have you added the screens of your game on the build settings panel?

Comment: I think that your Main Camera is not pointing at the objects that you have in the scene.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー my main camera is point at object as i have said everything works fines when i play the scene in unity editor

Comment: @NahuelIanni  I clicked on build&run and then select windows, mac platform for my game build . sorry but i didnt "add screen option" in build panel.

Answer (score 5):

This also happened with me when I started unity. I fixed this issue by adding a scene into my "Build settings" panel.  Before that, Unity was loading from sample scene which happened to be blue. I had to unselect this sample scene, and select a new scene, to make it run from my saved scene.

If the "Game" pane still shows blue, check that one of the scenes listed in your "Build Settings" panel is selected in the "Project" pane.

Comment: This answer solved my issue with one note. I expected my scene to be properly selected (under build settings) because there was only one available scene option in the list. After noticing "Add Open Scene" I clicked it and my correct scene was added to the list. I was then able to check it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to set your canvas scaler to scale with screen size.

Comment: Thanks for reply but How would i add canvas scaler to screen size? i dnt even know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I tried to upgrade my version of Unity, the upgrade failed, and I had to revert to an old version.

Specifically, I had the change on a git branch and reverted all the files back to my master branch in git, but it did not revert the files in `.gitignore`.

I was finally able to fix this by closing `Unity`, deleting the `Temp` directory in the project, and restarting `Unity`.  Came right back up.  Note that I tried "Reimporting all assets" before and that did not solve it.  I needed to delete `Temp`.